# Joomla .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, joomla, url-rewriting

I need a working RewriteRule to get rid of the `/index.php/category/` part of my url(s).

```
bruteforce.tv/index.php/streams/shinigamily
bruteforce.tv/index.php/streams/cash
bruteforce.tv/index.php/streams/blacktigrex
bruteforce.tv/index.php/streams/viktorwwe
```

TO

```
bruteforce.tv/shinigamily
bruteforce.tv/cash
bruteforce.tv/blacktigrex
bruteforce.tv/viktorwwe
```

I'm not used to it with working with a htaccess file so I apologize for being completely unresourceful.

This is my current htaccess file with the not working `RewriteRule ^streams/(.*)/?$ /$1 [L,NC,R]`

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

## Mod_rewrite in use.

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteRule ^streams/(.*)/?$ /$1 [L,NC,R]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /component/|(/[^.]*|\.(php|html?|feed|pdf|vcf|raw))$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

Comment: Any reason you're not using the Joomla feature to remove index.php? I'd start with that.

Comment: I dont know wich feature you mean. If its URL Rewrite, its enabled. But therefor a htaccess file is required.

Comment: My mistake. I forgot that that specific setting was removed in 2.5. That said, you shouldn't be seeing /index.php if rewrite is enabled.

Comment: Somebody told me "You need a redirect and a rewrite!". Still dont get how to do it :<

Answer (score 0):

1. Use Joomla's built-in feature to remove /index.php (under global config > site)
2. `RewriteRule ^streams/(.*)$ http://bruteforce.tv/$1 [R=301,L]`

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! It doesnt work when i replace your code with the previous one. Or may i replace your code with the entire code of the htaccess file? Just thought its needed to use RewriteEngine On and RewriteBase /. If I google oomla feature remove index.php, it shows me the same thing i just did. Enable the URL Rewrite in the Global Setup and rename the original htaccess.txt to .htaccess.

Comment: Try putting this line immediately below 'RewriteEngine on'. Don't remove any of the other lines. Those are there for security reasons.

Comment: And what's the URL you get the 404 at?

Comment: Ah wait. Only http://bruteforce.tv/shinigamily gets 404. The other 3 links work but the /streams/ is still there. So Nothing changed.

Comment: Firstly you need to find out why rewrite isn't working. You shouldn't be seeing /index.php. When that's sorted, worry about remvoving /streams/. I'd replace your .htaccess file with the contents of the one from your Joomla package download and start fresh. Rename your existing one first to archive it.

Comment: Removing index.php works fine. Only thing thats not working is removing the catogory name.